# How to convert a List of objects into a Map<String, Integer> with auto-generated values?

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream

I have `List<City> cities`. I need to convert `cities` into a map `Map<String, Integer>`, where the value (`Integer`) has to be auto-generated.

I tried this, but it seems not allowed to use `counter` like that because of atomic error. Ho to solve this task?

```
public Map<String, Integer> convertListToMap(List<City> cities) {
    Integer counter=0;
    return cities.stream().forEach(elem->tollFreeVehicles.put(elem.getName(), counter++));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables that are allowed to be used in the lambda expressions needs to be ***final*** or ***effectively final***.

Have a look at the [Oracle's tutorial on lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). A short excerpt:

> a lambda expression can only access local variables and parameters of
> the enclosing block that are final or effectively final. In this
> example, the variable z is effectively final; its value is never
> changed after it's initialized.

You can construct a *map* from a *list* using indices of items in the *list* as *values* by utilizing [`IntStream.range()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int)).

Also note that [`forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) doesn't return a value. In order to generate a *map* as a result of the execution of the stream pipeline that will be returned from the method, you need to use `collect()` as terminal operation.

```
Map<String, Integer> result = 
    IntStream.range(0, cities.size())
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> cities.get(i).getName(),
                                       Function.identity()));
```